# Excel: Detect #N/A (German: #NV) for conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a huge Excel sheet where I regularly import mass data into. This data is input to calculations per row. Sometimes, the imported data results in a #NV error in the calculated data.

I would like to be informed when that happens. So I thought, I would use conditional formatting on one single cell if Excel finds #NV in a range which is input for formatting evaluation formula.

Do you know a way to detect #NV in a range via a formula? Seems that isnv() triggers only if all cells in a range are #NV.

I am on Excel 2003.

Edit: adapted title to English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example, assume the range of cells you want to check is `B1:B15`. Also, I have assumed that #NV is the German Excel equivalent of #N/A. You can use the `COUNTIF` function combined with `NV()` to essentially count how many cells in the range evaluate to #NV.

Enter this in the conditional formatting formula:

```
=COUNTIF(B1:B15,NV()) > 0
```

Quite simply, this means that the cell should have the defined formatting applied if there is at least one cell within `B1:B15` that is #NV. Note the English equivalent would be:

```
=COUNTIF(B1:B15,NA()) > 0
```